# Cypress error RPC executor service threw an error

Tags: cypress, ui-automation, rpc

I’m new using Cypress and I’m trying to go to gmail to get a password recovery email.
The scenario is, I am on a page requesting password recovery and I must go to gmail to get the recovery link, but after entering the email and give next, this error comes out:
**RPC executor service threw an error!**
If I try to run the browser incognito shows me a different error regarding cookies.
Some One can help me.
Thanks.

If I try to run the browser incognito shows me a different error regarding cookies.
I modified the settings of the normal chrome session but the error continues.
I need log in in gmail and get the recover link.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?